# Run 2 python scripts using crontab

Tags: python, cron

This is my first crontab file. its work fine to execute `logDHT.py`
but will it work if i just add this line of code under the last line of my crontab?
The line of code that i want to add:

```
* * 1 * * pi /usr/bin/python /home/pi/Sensors_Database/checkDB.py
```

My First Crontab:

```
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command

1 * * * * pi /usr/bin/python /home/pi/Sensors_Database/logDHT.py
```

My goals is running 2 script at different time, with `logDHT.py` running every minute, and `checkDB.py` running every day.

Comment: You seem to know what you want - you seem to know how to do it - what exactly is your question?

Comment: this sign (;), some source said its require put the (;) between 2 line of code on crontab. my Pi at home now, i cant just type and try the code so i ask this problem

Comment: I don't know what is stopping you from testing it - but the way crontab works is that each line in a new scheduled task. You do not need a semicolon (although you can use one to run multiple scripts in succession, not what you seem to want here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `pi /usr/bin/python /home/pi/Sensors_Database/checkDB.py` how you normally run the script if you were to run it from CLI?

Here is an example from my own crontab:

```
0 * * * * ~/.duckdns/duck.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
0 * * * * python ~/flagstatus.py >/dev/null 2>&1
```

As you can see, the first line is a bash script, and the second line is a python script. If I were to run my `flagstatus.py` script from the command line, this is exactly what I would type in: `python ~/flagstatus.py` and that's exactly what goes into crontab. The `>/dev/null 2>&1` part at the end just tells cron that I don't want any output (i.e. no logs, etc). It's optional, just depends on if you want cron to create logs/send messages about the scirpts output.

Comment: no, its not normaly the way i run the script on CLI. google said /usr/bin/python is represent what python version we used. i used python 2. so the (;) not required on the end of first line ? well thank you for your suggestion :)

Comment: one thing left, how to check the logs about scripts execution ?

Comment: `sudo cat /var/log/cron`